# optimize updates to DataTable bound to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have a Form in my application that displays some data. When I first show the Form, I load some data into a DataTable then bind the DataTable to a DataGridView. I also start an asynchronous method that executes some slower database queries. When these slow queries complete, I need to update a few hundred rows in the DataTable, filling in values returned from the slower queries, like so:

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    SlowLoadingData slow_stuff = slow_query_results[(int)row["id"]];

    row.BeginEdit();
    row[column_one] = slow_stuff.One;
    row[column_two] = slow_stuff.Two;
    row[column_three] = slow_stuff.Three;
    row.EndEdit();
}
```

This is extremely slow, hanging the UI thread for a minute or more, presumably because each row is triggering a redraw.

After some research, I found a way to make it fast. First, bind the DataGridView to a BindingSource that is bound to the DataTable, instead of directly to the DataTable. Then, do as follows when you make changes to the DataTable:

```
binding_source.SuspendBinding();
binding_source.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
// foreach (DataRow in Data.Rows) ... code above
binding_source.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
binding_source.ResumeBinding();
grid.Refresh();
```

There is a problem, though, and it's a doozy: the code above prevents the DataGridView from detecting new rows added to the DataTable. **Any new rows added to the table do not appear in the grid.** The grid may also throw exceptions if you use the arrow keys to move the current cell selection off the bottom end of the grid, because the underlying data source has more rows but the grid has not created grid rows to display them.

So, two possible solutions that I can see:

1. Is there a better way to suppress binding updates while making changes to the underlying DataTable?
2. Is there an easy way to tell the DataGridView to gracefully refresh its grid row collection to match the number of underlying DataTable rows? (Note: I've tried calling BindingSource.ResetBindings, but it seems to trigger more exceptions if you have *removed* rows from the DataTable!)

Comment: I don't know much about using binding source, but does doing resumebinding before setting raiselistchangedevents to true do any difference?

Comment: I have tried all possible orders of calling the methods. All that is required for the grid to screw up is that RaiseListChangedEvents be false when the new row is added.

Comment: Call a function called ResetBindings to force the UI to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered disconnecting the dataGrid or the bindingSource while filling the table and reconnecting afterwards? It might look a bit ugly, but it should be a lot faster.

Comment: This works, but it's not a pleasant user experience, largely because the grid will scroll back to the top when you un-bind then re-bind the table. Perhaps I'm just an optimist but I hope find a more graceful solution.

Comment: You can reposition the row, and tweak it a little to minimze screen redraws. Probably reconnect grid to source as very last step.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the [Merge method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) on the DataTable. I'll try to create a simple demo app and post it here, but the idea is simple. When you want to update the Grid, query the results into a new DataTable, and then merge the old table with the new table. As long as both tables have primary keys (you can create them them im memory if they don't come back from the DB) then it should track changes and update the DataGridView seamlessly. It also has the advantage of not losing the users place on the grid.

OK, here's a sample. I create a form with two buttons and one dataGridView. On button1 click, I populate the main table with some data, and bind the grid to it. Then, on second click, I create another table with the same schema. Add data to it (some that have the same primary key, and some that have new ones). Then, they merge them back to the original table. It updates the grid as expected.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataTable mainTable;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.mainTable = this.CreateTestTable();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                this.mainTable.Rows.Add(String.Format("Person{0}", i), i * i);
            }

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.mainTable;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable newTable = this.CreateTestTable();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                newTable.Rows.Add(String.Format("Person{0}", i), i + i);
            }
            this.mainTable.Merge(newTable);
        }

        private DataTable CreateTestTable()
        {
            var result = new DataTable();
            result.Columns.Add("Name");
            result.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            result.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { result.Columns["Name"] };

            return result;

        }
    }
```

Comment: This does seem efficient, and it solves the new-row dilemma, but I see two drawbacks: the grid seems to reset its scroll to the *selected row* (not be the same as the "user's place"), and merging correctly requires that you create a copy of the whole target table (might be large).

Comment: Sure there is a copy. You have to make a new table to merge in the new data. This new table has to have the same data as the old table + the changes you want merged.

Comment: Henk is right. You don't have to have the old values in the new table. I just did that to demonstrate that *if* there are rows that have the same primary keys, with different values in one of the columns, it correctly does an *update* however you don't *need* to duplicate the data from the 1st table

Comment: In my main scenario, I need to update ALL rows in the table. Therefore, my merge table will be a duplicate of the original table with the desired changes applied to each row. I'm fairly sure I'm right about this because I tested out how it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `BindingSource` for complex data binding, it's important to understand that `SuspendBinding` and `ResumeBinding` only suspend and resume binding *for the current item.*  This lets you disable binding for the current item and change a bunch of its properties without any of the individual changes to the property being pushed out to the bound control.  (This isn't explained in the documentation for the `BindingSource`, where it would be useful, oh no:  it's in the documentation for the `CurrencyManager`.)

Any changes you make to the other items in the list, i.e. everything except the current item, raise the `ListChanged` event.  If you disable these events, the BindingSource stops telling the bound control about changes to the list until you re-enable them.  This has the result you've seen:  you add all of your rows to the underlying `DataTable`, but since you've turned `ListChanged` events off, the `BindingSource` doesn't tell the `DataGridView` about them, and so the `DataGridView` remains empty.

The proper solution is to call `ResetBindings`, which forces the `BindingSource` to refresh all of the controls bound to it, using the current values in its bound list.

What sort of exceptions are you getting after you call `ResetBindings`?  Because it works just fine for me, whether I add, edit, delete, or remove rows from the underlying `DataTable`.

Comment: Testing with my co-worker's code, we observed a lot of weirdness after calling ResetBindings, including phantom grid rows and IndexOutOfRange exceptions thrown by the grid. Will experiment more today to see whether something else is going on.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem. Here's a solution that is even simpler (if less elegant).

I found that this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataTable.BeginLoadData();
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows){
    //modify row
}
dataTable.EndLoadData();
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

...is way faster than this:

```
dataTable.BeginLoadData();
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows){
    //modify row
}
dataTable.EndLoadData();
```

Cheers--DC

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this as a solution: Making some notations to the comments and posts already.
The Merge Table method mentioned by BFree is a very good method to use and I think is the right approach not too mention very simple and elegant.
Here are my notes why and the big one I am not sure if any one caught was the hits on the server for the query.
The op stated in his comments to BFree that he would need to copy the table to do what he needed to, of course which table that was I am not sure , because his code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
```

Those rows come from his table called data where is the copy required on that - he already has it.

Then here is something that just smacks right out on EACH Iteration of that loop :

```
SlowLoadingData slow_stuff = slow_query_results[(int)row["id"]];
```

Is the OP really querying the database each iteration of those rows (Which if it is a large table are we talking 100,000 rows +).
Think of the load on the Server (his app too must generate this query request!), and also the amount of traffic it places on a network to do this! 
IF it is the only app maybe it's ok, but even at that it is not what I would prefer to do if I wanted to be efficient.

If gathering the data from the database in one query seems to much - then perhaps a better method would be to page his data in and do the merge.

```
SlowLoadingData Page1_SlowLoadingData = slow_query_results[Page1] as DataTable;
data.Merge(Page1_SlowLoadingData);

SlowLoadingData Page2_SlowLoadingData = slow_query_results[Page2] as DataTable;
data.Merge(Page2_SlowLoadingData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using resetBindings seems to move the scrollbar and the user is left thinking what did i do? I found that using a bindingList as a datasource, with an object that uses INotifyPropertyChanged, and then when I edited the row, (bound to an object). the row wasnt being updated until a click or selection change on the form.

but calling dgv.Refresh() seemed to solve the problem, without the scroll change.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution by Ravi LVS on codeproject works well:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

bs.DataSource = dt;
bs.SuspendBinding();
bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; 
bs.Filter = "1=0"; 
dt.BeginLoadData(); 

//== some modification on data table

dt.EndLoadData();
bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
bs.Filter = "";
```

Link to original page: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55730/Achieve-performance-while-updating-a-datatable-bou