# c# Async/Await not updating UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I am learning to implement async/await on one of my task which takes a long time to complete. Once the task is completed, it should update the DGV.

```
    private async void frmA_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some codes to accept dropped files

        // Run task asynchronously
        Task<DataTable> task = Task.Run(() => PDF.CheckPDFs(Files, tblPDFs));
        dgvPDF.DataSource = await task;
     }
```

I found that after the task is completed, it is not updating the DGV. So, I added the InvokeRequired bit to manually update the table and also to prevent cross-thread exception.

```
        // Update UI
        if (dgvPDF.InvokeRequired)
        {
            dgvPDF.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { dgvPDF.Refresh(); }));
        }
        else
        {
            dgvPDF.Refresh();
        }
```

I also have a separate event handler which highlights the row red is a file is invalid:

```
    private void dgvPDF_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvPDF["Pages",e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() == "0")
            dgvPDF.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;
    }
```

What happened is that the RowAdded event handler is not triggered at all. If I made the code synchronous i.e removing await/async and invoke, everything works fine except with the UI freezing

My question is using InvokedRequired the correct way to update the UI in async await? What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Refresh() is not intended to use for "update the table". For async process, data binding should be care when use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667571/optimize-updates-to-datatable-bound-to-datagridview

Comment: Could you post the source code for `PDF.CheckPDFs`?

Comment: I suspect that `PDF.CheckPDFs` contains some work that can be done in the background and some that must be done on the UI thread. If I can see that I should be able to help you refactor this to behave as you expect.

Comment: I was struggling witch the same problem, if you trigger lots of events in short period of time everything freezes. I usually end up with using the main thread or backgroundworker.

Answer (score 1):

no, you don't have to "invoke", the context will switch back after async method call complete, i.e., the statements after await will get executed in UI thread.